# Google App maker Architecture

Tags: google-app-maker

We do not see app maker architecture in the documentation, Is there any diagrammatic representation of app maker architecture.

Can anyone suggest how can we represent the architecture of app maker

Answer (score 3):

**App Maker Editor**

There is nothing special about App Maker Editor, it is an ordinary web app that allows you to create other web apps and publish them, what leads us to App Maker's runtime.

**App Maker Runtime**

App Maker uses [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) as runtime for apps built with it. In other words App Maker creates an Apps Script project for app's deployments. Why is it important? Because it means that App Maker apps have almost the same powers as Apps Script apps such as tight integration with lots of [Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/) and [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/). OK.... you can ask "How Google Cloud Platform is related to App Maker and App Script?". Well, every Apps Script project (i.e. App Maker deployment) is bound to Google Cloud Platform project and the most trivial usages of GCP are logging, database access ([Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql)), configuring extra services, API keys, etc...

[image: Architecture]